# Multiple identities with only one account on Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, imap

I have many (~40) domains that are used for business purposes. Those domains are hosted on a SMTP/IMAP server, separated from our exchange server.

Right now, I have one IMAP account for each domain, but it's a hassle to manage (30 users * 40 domains, you do the maths...)
So, I would like to have only one imap account for all the domains, and use identities in Outlook. Which basically means that I need a way to change the From address with something that doesn't exist in the activ directory.

I tried to add a new SMTP address in the user profile in the activ directory, but this SMTP doesn't stay, and is replaced with the default SMTP address (the one from exchange) of the user when the email is sent

I know it works with thunderbird: you can define as many identities as you want. But we need to stay with outlook, and somehow find a way to have one exchange account and one IMAP account live together.

Is there a way to do that ?